# Dynamic add element to multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, addition, associative

I am trying to insert new element into multidimensional associative array like

```
$arr=array('ID' => 123,
           'name' => 'rock',
           'accountID' => 'u0777f7f-77f7-4d2e-9h7c-ea775d052785',
           'admin' => array  (
                       'main' => array (
                                   'stats' =>'', 
                                   'emails' =>'', 
                                   'calls' => ''
                                )
                         )
            );

 $list='';
 $list .="['admin']['main']['hello']";

 $arr{$list}='world';
 print_r($arr);
```

But new element is not getting added to ['admin']['main'], instead of that it is creating new array element like

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 123
    [name] => rock
    [accountID] => u0777f7f-77f7-4d2e-9h7c-ea775d052785
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [main] => Array
                (
                    [stats] => 
                    [emails] => 
                    [calls] => 
                )

        )
   [['admin']['main']['hello']] => world
)
```

Please help me to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: You need to solve it in that manner ?

Comment: What about `$arr['admin']['main']['hello'] = 'world';`?

Comment: Why are you putting array indices into a string and then de-referencing this string?

Comment: I am getting add/insert element dynamic as array or array within array. I don't know whether I need to add a element into existing array like [admin][main][hello] or something new like [hello]=>'world'

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
$arr['admin']['main']['hello'] = > 'world';
```

OR

```
$main = $arr['admin']['main'];
$main['hello'] = 'world';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. What if I want to add new array in $arr somwthing like
Array
(
    [ID] => 123
    [name] => rock
    [accountID] => u0777f7f-77f7-4d2e-9h7c-ea775d052785
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [main] => Array
                (
                    [stats] => 
                    [emails] => 
                    [calls] => 
                )

        )
   [hello] => world
)

Answer (score 0):

```
[['admin']['main']['hello']] => world
```

it's because $list considered by **STRING**

**try to change this line**

```
$list='';
$list .="['admin']['main']['hello']"; 
$arr{$list}='world';
print_r($arr);
```

**with**

```
$list = array();
$list['main']['hello'] = "world";
$arr['admin'] = $list;
print_r($arr);
```

The magic will be revealed. lol

---

If you wanted $arr like:

```
Array ( 
     [ID] => 123 
     [name] => rock 
     [accountID] => u0777f7f-77f7-4d2e-9h7c-ea775d052785 
     [admin] => Array ( 
                    [main] => Array ( 
                         [stats] => 
                         [emails] => 
                         [calls] => 
                                    ) 
                       ) 
     [hello] => world 
      )
```

**you can write logically**

```
$arr = array();

$arr['ID'] = 123;
$arr['name'] = "rock";
$arr['accountID'] = "u0777f7f-77f7-4d2e-9h7c-ea775d052785";

$arr['admin']['main']['stats'] = "complete";
$arr['admin']['main']['emails'] = "example@email.com";
$arr['admin']['main']['calls'] = "yourfunction";
$arr['hello'] = "world";
```